# create a model in create action from a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

As a newbie to rails I can't find how to solve my issue ^^
I want to create a VideoPost from a form with a text field containing a video url (like youtube)
I'm getting information on the video thanks to the gem https://github.com/thibaudgg/video_info
And I want to save thoses information using a model of mine (VideoInformation).
But I don't know how the create process should work.
Thanks for any help !

I'm trying to create a VideoPost in VideoPostsController like this :

```
def create
  video_info = VideoInfo.new(params[:video_url])
  video_information = VideoInformation.create(video_info)      #undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Youtube:0x00000006a24120>
  if video_information.save
    @video_post = current_user.video_posts.build(video_information) 
  end
end
```

My VideoPost model :

```
# Table name: video_posts
#
#  id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id              :integer
#  video_information_id :integer
#  created_at           :datetime         not null
#  updated_at           :datetime         not null
```

My VideoInformation model (which got same attributes name than VideoInfo gem) :

```
# Table name: video_informations
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  title           :string(255)
#  description     :text
#  keywords        :text
#  duration        :integer
#  video_url       :string(255)
#  thumbnail_small :string(255)
#  thumbnail_large :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a method to the VideoInformation model so you can create one by passing in video_info:

```
# app/models/video_information.rb
def self.create_from_video_info(video_info, url)
  video_information = self.new
  video_information.title = video_info.title
  video_information.description = video_info.description
  video_information.keywords = video_info.keywords
  video_information.duration = video_info.duration
  # video_url appears to not be available on video_info,
  # maybe you meant embed_url?
  video_information.video_url = url
  video_information.thumbnail_small = video_info.thumbnail_small
  video_information.thumbnail_large = video_info.thumbnail_large
  video_information.save
  video_information
end

# app/controllers/video_posts_controller.rb
def create
  video_info = VideoInfo.new(params[:video_url])
  video_information = VideoInformation.create_from_video_info(video_info, params[:video_url])

  if video_information.valid?
    current_user.video_posts << video_information
  end
end
```

Also, you may want to look at doing this a different way. It seems redundant to have `VideoInformation`, `VideoInfo` and `VideoPost` classes.

Maybe the `VideoPost` model could simply store the URL of the video, and you could pull in the `VideoInfo` stuff on the fly as you need it when rendering/using `VideoPost` instances.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This may work I'm gonna try it. But I was thinking rails had a elegant and simpler way of doing that :/ I have two different models because I plan to add associations in VideoInformation in a future ^^ (And that way I avoid to call youtube api everytime)

Comment: video_url hasn't to be stored in VideoInfo, it is the value from the form on the new page used to create the Object. Usage : VideoInfo.new("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZqGqE0D0n4")

Answer (score 3):

> don't know how the create process should work

`create` method expects a hash with parameters, not some arbitrary object. You should use methods of VideoInfo and convert it to a hash which will be consumable by ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is no such methods in VideoInfo I think, I tried video_information = VideoInformation.new(video_info.attributes) but it return the error "undefined method `attributes' for #<Youtube:0x0000000670af20>". How could I convert it to a hash ? (In fact I was thinking that rails did it himself implicitly)

Comment: There are methods for getting individual pieces of information. You can use them to build your hash. See @JasonNoble's answer, for example.

Comment: Erf ok thanks. I was thinking rails had an elegant and simpler way to do that :/